# When does circular dependency become a problem?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, circular-dependency

I tried `madge` on a TypeScript app that I'm working on:

```
npx madge --circular --extensions ts src/
```

And got a long dump of circular dependencies (61 of them actually). The thing is however that app compiles and works fine. How is this possible? Are there certain conditions when circular dependencies turn into the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Synchronous* circular imports are fine, generally. Think of them as declarations, they don't actually perform anything. Just as long as you don't *use* the imports immediately, synchronously. For instance, this works:

**A.js:**

```js
import B from 'B.js'

export function A() {
  if (/* some condition that doesn't last forever */) return B()
  else return 0 // of course, you don't want an infinite recursive loop either ;)
}
```

**B.js:**

```js
import A from 'A.js'

export function B() {
  if (/* some condition that doesn't last forever */) return A()
  else return 0 // same thing
}
```

You can import A and B in another file, and call both of them there, it'll be fine. A and B refer to each other but they don't need to *use* each other until one of them is called.

But if you *use* one of the two exports synchronously while the other isn't exported yet, that will fail:

**A.js:**

```js
import B from 'B.js'

export const A = B(something)
```

**B.js:**

```js
import A from 'A.js'

export function B() {
  return A
}
```

Now what happens here is that the *evaluation* of A (which must be performed before exporting it) requires calling B, and running B requires that A is already defined.

Comment: Is there a way (in `madge` or any other tool) to dump out only synchronous circular dependencies?

Comment: I don't know. Circular dynamic imports will definitely cause an error, so you should really worry about them rather than synchronous imports (the latter are often bundled together into a single file during your build process anyway).

Comment: I just avoid circular depedencies in their entirety in typescript by using a master exports index.  Export EVERYTHING via one root index, and import EVERYTHING from that root index.  Zero relative or individual file imports.  You can export folders via child indexes etc, and export those from the master index.  But doing this gives you one nice pretty graph in madge.   Then rely on webpack or rollup tree shaking to drop stuff you aren't using.  If you have clashing names, just namespace the export, like 'export * as things from './someIndex''

Comment: I don't see how that avoids circular dependencies. You're just making them indirect. Instead of "A requires B from B.js" and "B requires A from A.js", you'll have "A requires B from the index" and "B requires A from the index", with the index reexporting both A and B from their respective files (possibly by going through more indexes).